# CKEditor fakeObject css pseudo element ::before

Tags: ckeditor

Originally I was planning to use Widgets to handle font-awesome icons just like available CKEditor FontAwesome plugins do. It turned out that we needed widgets for contact information and would like to use user selectable icons within those widgets. Since CKEditor < 4.5 doesn't support widgets within widgets I resorted into using fakeObject plugin instead.

The problem is that IE doesn't support img::before and CKEditor.createFakeParserElement uses images.

HTML for FontAwesome is like `<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-lg"></i>` and CSS .fa::before pseudo element is used to display the icon.

Is there a reason why CKEditor fakeObject uses img tag, is it related to CKEDITOR.dtdView.$removeEmpty or can I just make fakeObject2 based on original fakeObject and use div instead of img?

How to make empty span or i -tag removal conditional in a way that if span has certain classes it will not be removed and will be removed otherwise (if span or i has class "fa" and is empty don't remove)?